# Git Windows - Git clone gets stuck indefnitely

Tags: git

I am new to using git.
I have installed the git on Windows 8 and have set up the id_rsa key in the "C:/Users/${Username}/.ssh" folder.

After setting up the keys the git clone worked fine for first 2-3 times and after that when I am trying to git clone it gets stuck indefinitely with message below

Cloning into someprojectname....

Only the "someprojectname" folder is created with a .git folder in it and nothing clones after that and no error is thrown.

Any body has idea why this may be happening or some pointers for further debugging/logs

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use your powershell prompt for git usage, it should give you similar like experience to linux or mac users.

From there try to clone the repo you need. Please refer to this link with any further issues,https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a known problem with SSH cloning, for me cloning with HTTP did the trick in the same situation.